# DataTable Select Implementation with Multiple AND Conditions

Tags: c#, performance, select, datatable

I have a DataTable with about 50,000 rows that I'm using `DataTable.Select` to retrieve rows from.  The `Select` requires multiple `AND` conditions including a wildcard match.  I've played around and found that by doing the same `Select` in multiple steps, the execution time can be greatly reduced, but changing the order of the `AND` statements doesn't affect it.

```
//This takes ~ 750 ms
DataRow[] results = myDataTable.Select("Field1 LIKE '*" + term1 + "*'" +
"AND Field2 = '" + term2 + "'" +
"AND Field3 = '" + term3 + "'");

//This also takes ~750 ms
DataRow[] results2 = myDataTable.Select("Field3 = '" + term3 + "'" +
"AND Field2 = '" + term2 + "'" +
"AND Field1 LIKE '*" + term1 + "*'");  

//This takes 0.415 ms
DataTable table1 = myDataTable.Select("Field3 = '" + term3+ "'").CopyToDataTable();
DataTable table2 = table1.Select("Field2 = '" + term2 + "'").CopyToDataTable();
DataRow [] results3 = table2.Select("Field1 LIKE '*" + term1 + "*'");
```

My question is, is there a way to always make the `SELECT` operation evaluate `AND` conditions in a left-to-right order so that number of records searched would be reduced between steps?  It would seem this could be a good time saver. Thank you for your ideas.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use `Linq` (note that the slowest condition is the last):

```
IEnumerable<DataRow> rows = myDataTable.AsEnumerable()
    .Where(r => r.Field<string>("Field2") == term2
            &&  r.Field<string>("Field3") == term3
            &&  r.Field<string>("Field1").Contains(term1));
```

Use `CopyToDataTable` if you want to create a new DataTable from the result, `ToArray` to create a `DataRow[]` or leave it and use `foreach` to enumerate the result without creating a new collection.

Comment: Thanks for the tip Tim, this has increased performance greatly!

Answer (score 1):

Nope.. a datatable does a select row by row.

You can write your code a bit shorter:

```
DataRow [] results = myDataTable
     .Select("Field3 = '" + term3+ "'").CopyToDataTable()
     .Select("Field2 = '" + term2 + "'").CopyToDataTable()
     .Select("Field1 LIKE '*" + term1 + "*'");
```

Or... if you make an extra extension method, like this:

static public DataRow[] Select(this IEnumerable rows, string filter)
{
     return rows.CopyToDataTable().Select(filter);
}

Using this extension makes your code even shorter:

```
DataRow [] results = myDataTable
     .Select("Field3 = '" + term3+ "'")
     .Select("Field2 = '" + term2 + "'")
     .Select("Field1 LIKE '*" + term1 + "*'");
```

Or:

```
static public DataRow[] Select(this DataTable dt, string firstFilter, params string[] filters)
{
    DataRow[] result = dt.Select(firstFilter);
    foreach(string filter in filters)
        result = result.CopyToDataTable().Select(filter);
    return result;
}
```

Opening up the way to:

```
DataRow [] results = myDataTable.Select(
    "Field3 = '" + term3+ "'", 
    "Field2 = '" + term2 + "'",
    "Field1 LIKE '*" + term1 + "*'");
```

Comment: This creates two new `DataTables` and three `DataRow[]` in memory just to filter a table, very inefficient.

Comment: Correct... I stayed as close to his solution as possible for compatability. I admid your solution is much better and fast, but I can imagine that more a complex criteria (with ? in like, etc.) would throw up new problems like having to use regex, etc.