# filter datatable based on condition

Tags: c#, asp.net, datatable, dropdown

I have a text file with a list of PrinterName,Ip,description, and ConnectionStringID

example

```
Name,Ip,Description,connectionstringID
gkbzpl01,12.43.13,425,2nd floor,Datatable
ackzpl201,13.44.65,324,1st floor,Datatable
```

I load this into a drop downlist as such:

```
 protected void LoadPrinterList()
    {

        string CSVFilePathName = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FilePath"];
        string[] Lines = File.ReadAllLines(CSVFilePathName);
        string[] Fields;
        Fields = Lines[0].Split(new char[] { ',' });
        int Cols = Fields.GetLength(0);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        //1st row must be column names; force lower case to ensure matching later on.
        for (int i = 0; i < Cols; i++)
            dt.Columns.Add(Fields[i].ToLower(), typeof(string));
        dt.Columns.Add("nameanddescription", typeof(string), "name +'-'+ description");
        dt.Columns.Add("ipandconnectionstring", typeof(string), "ip +'-'+ ConncetionStringID");
        DataRow Row;
        for (int i = 1; i < Lines.GetLength(0); i++)
        {
            Fields = Lines[i].Split(new char[] { ',' });
            Row = dt.NewRow();
            for (int f = 0; f < Cols; f++)
                Row[f] = Fields[f];
             dt.Rows.Add(Row);
        }

        string hostname = Request.UserHostName.Substring(0, 3);
        string[] name = Printerlist.SelectedValue.Split('-');
        //string plant = name[0].ToString();
        //string plantvalue = plant.Substring(0, 3);
        //if(hostname == plantvalue)
        //{
        Printerlist.DataTextField = "nameanddescription";
        Printerlist.DataValueField = "ipandconnectionstring";
        //}
        Printerlist.DataSource = dt;
        Printerlist.DataBind();


    }
```

the above works wonderfully but now I need to display only the label printers that pertain to that particular plant, there are a total of 4 plants each of which have 5 or more printers and 2 test printers that I have access to in the corporate building.

so this is what I have so far

```
 string servername = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Host;
            string firstthreeserver = servername.Substring(0, 3);
            string clientname = HttpContext.Current.Server.MachineName;
            string firstthreeclient = clientname.Substring(0, 3).ToLower();
            if (firstthreeserver.ToLower() == firstthreeclient.ToLower())
            {
                DataRow[] result = dt.Select("nameanddescription Like '%" + firstthreeclient + "%'");
                for (int i = 1; i < Lines.GetLength(0); i++)
                {
                    Fields = Lines[i].Split(new char[] { ',' });
                    Row = dt.NewRow();
                      for (int f = 0; f < Cols; f++)
                          Row[f] = Fields[f];
                      dt.Rows.Add(result);
                }
            }
                else
                {
                    string test = "tes".ToLower();
                    foreach (var row in dt.Select("nameanddescription like '%" + test  + "%'" ))
                    {
                         dt.ImportRow(row);
                    }
                }
```

so I get the server name (gkbserv) and the client that is accessing the application from the server (gkb001) I take the first three letters and compare if the above it true then display gkbzpl01-2ndfloor in the drop down list. if the above is not true then display the two test printers. **how do I filter the data table to only show me the records that satisfy the like condition??**

Comment: it looks like you have used dt.Select to try to filter with the "like" operator already.. did you get an error message with this approach?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `DataTable.Select` method to filter the Rows which satisfies the condition. You can read more details [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/det4aw50%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). For using the filters please refer [here](http://www.csharp-examples.net/dataview-rowfilter/).

Comment: I tried the datatable.select method, and like but that isn't returning any rows?? let me check your links

Answer (score 0):

I think this can help: [DataTable Select Implementation with Multiple AND Conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16219521/datatable-select-implementation-with-multiple-and-conditions) (2 and 3-d comments)

```
 IEnumerable<DataRow> rows = myDataTable.AsEnumerable()
.Where(r => r.Field<string>("Field2") == term2
        &&  r.Field<string>("Field3") == term3
        &&  r.Field<string>("Field1").Contains(term1));

 DataRow [] results = myDataTable
 .Select("Field3 = '" + term3+ "'")
 .Select("Field2 = '" + term2 + "'")
 .Select("Field1 LIKE '*" + term1 + "*'");
```